# how to execute an arithmetic program in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL so I have tried to execute some PL/SQL programs in SQL developer. But it throws an error, even my program was correct. Is there any need to change my SQL Developer settings to perform mathematical operations?

I was tying to execute this program.

```
DECLARE
    num number(5):= 20;
    num1 number(5):= 80; 
    sum number(5);
BEGIN
    sum:= num + num1;
    dbms_output.put_line('result='||sum);
END;
```

and the error was :
Error starting at line : 2 in command -

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 36:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   (
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using reserved keyword `sum` as identifier which is not allowed.

Try this:

```
DECLARE
    num number(5):= 20;
    num1 number(5):= 80; 
    v_sum number(5);
BEGIN
    v_sum:= num + num1;
    dbms_output.put_line('result='||v_sum);
END;
```